# WPF UI auto fill text box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm writing WPF MVVM application in .Net 4.5 and need help with following problem:
I have text box with numerical value for example 110000 and when both 11 are deleted UI auto fill box with number 0. Instead i would like it to stay with 0000.
Picture to help illustrate problem.

[image: Picture]

**Edit**

```
<src:CustomTextBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
 Text="{Binding TrafoProperties.RatedVoltage, 
 Mode=TwoWay,
 ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,
 NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
```

Code for custom text box it set PropertyChanged by default

```
    static CustomTextBox()
   {
    var defaultMetadata = TextBox.TextProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(TextBox));

    TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
        defaultMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback,
        defaultMetadata.CoerceValueCallback, 
        true, 
        System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged)); 
   }
```

Property

```
        public double RatedVoltage
    {
        get { return _RatedVoltage; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _RatedVoltage, value);
            if (OnRatedVoltageChanged != null)
                OnRatedVoltageChanged();
        }
    }
```

It seams that text box is binded to double property and when it changes to 0000 its auto corrects it to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea...

Add a level of indirection between RatedVoltage property and CutomTextBox.

- Introduce a new string property to bind with your control. For e.g., name it RatedVoltageText.
- Bind CustomTextBox to RatedVoltageText, Mode = TwoWay.
- Whenever the double value of RatedVoltageText changes, make sure that RatedVoltage is also changed. (It's important that you compare (double)RatedVoltageText with RatedVoltage, and not RatedVoltageText with RatedVoltage.ToString())
- Whenver RatedVoltage changes, update RatedVoltageText if and only if the double representation of RatedVoltageText is different from the new value of RatedVoltage.

Here is a code sample that will do what I just outlined.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleRibbonWinodw.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleRibbonWinodw"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Gray">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGray" Content="SomeValueText (string)"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeValueText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGray" Content="SomeValue (double)"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ,Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Background="Wheat" BorderBrush="Black"/>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace SimpleRibbonWinodw
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChangedEvent;
        }

        private void HandlePropertyChangedEvent(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.Equals(e.PropertyName, nameof(SomeValueText), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                double result;
                if (Double.TryParse(SomeValueText, out result))
                {
                    // Do not allow property changed event
                    if (SomeValue != result)
                    {
                        SomeValue = result;
                        Debug.WriteLine($"New value of SomeValue = {SomeValue}");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (string.Equals(e.PropertyName, nameof(SomeValue), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                double result;
                if (Double.TryParse(SomeValueText, out result))
                {
                    if (result != SomeValue)
                    {
                        SomeValueText = SomeValue.ToString();
                        Debug.WriteLine($"New value of SomeValueText = {SomeValueText}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SomeValueText = SomeValue.ToString();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"New value of SomeValueText = {SomeValueText}");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public double SomeValue
        {
            get { return _someValue; }
            set
            {
                _someValue = value;
                Debug.WriteLine($"SomeValue Changed: {_someValue}");
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(SomeValue));
            }
        }

        private double _someValue;

        public string SomeValueText
        {
            get { return _someValueText;  }
            set
            {
                _someValueText = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(SomeValueText));
            }
        }

        private string _someValueText;

        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The result would look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Show some code.

From what you have stated, I suggest you to handle `TextChanged` event and check for the changed value. If its 0, put 0000 in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Num,StringFormat=0000}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already pointed out the root cause. Since you are using two-way mode data binding and PropertyChanged as UpdateSourceTrigger, once the data binding is triggered, 0000 will be corrected to a valid value(0). The solution depends on your use case, you can use LostFocus as UpdateSourceTrigger and perform a final validation when binding is triggered, and supplemented with TextChanged event for immediate validation when user typing.